# Отключение стилей автозаполнения

Tags: css, css3

При авто-заполнении инпутов, Chrome выставляет следующие стили для авто-заполненных полей. Как эти стили перекрыть или отключить? Именно стили, а не само по себе автозаполение.

[image: стили автозаполнения]

[image: user-agent стили Google Chrome]

И следующий код не отключает стили автозаполнения:

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: Вы не должны этого хотеть

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот что говорит MDN про [:-webkit-autofill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:-webkit-autofill):

> Note: The user agent style sheets of many browsers use !important in
>   their `:-webkit-autofill` style declarations, making them
>   non-overrideable by webpages without resorting to JavaScript hacks.
>
> ---
>
> Cтили, добавляемые многими браузерами через user agent, содержат `!important` в объявлении свойства `:-webkit-autofill` , запрещая его перезапись без вмешательства хаков Javascript

Можно выкрутиться, применив хитрости:

---

1) в случае, если фон `input` должен быть какого-либо цвета, но не прозрачный:

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 50px white inset; /* можно изменить на любой вариант цвета */
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #333;
}
```

в этом случае мы заливаем содержимое `input` применением внутренней тени желаемого цвета поверх цвета фона, устанавливаемого `user agent stylesheet` в `Chrome`

---

2) можно установить задержку на анимацию "пожелтения" фона на большой промежуток времени, тем самым давая возможность пользователю ввести свои данные и не увидеть желтый фон достаточно долго:

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
    transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s; /* выставляется желаемая задержка */
}
```

---

Подсмотрено на SO.com: [Removing input background colour for Chrome autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete)

Comment: Первый вариант не сработал. Второй сработал. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте! Попробуйте через скрипт

```
$("input[type='text']").bind('focus', function() {
   $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
});
```

или же

```
input:focus {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

html

```
<body onload="loadPage();">
```

js

```
 function loadPage()
    {
        if (document.login)//if the form login exists, focus:
        {
            document.login.name.focus();//the username input
            document.login.pass.focus();//the password input
            document.login.login.focus();//the login button (submitbutton)
        }
    }
```

Вот ссылка на источник - [Ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2416597/4443899)